# UWP - Lots of new compiler warnings when changing to ARM from x86, with previously OK solution

Tags: uwp, windows-10-universal

I have an app I've been working on for ages, successfully building and running on my local laptop and Windows 10 mobile.

I just refactored a namespace and made some other changes in the manifest.  The app still compiles without errors and runs on my laptop using x86, but now when I change to ARM I get a lot of errors (169) and warnings (7).  If I change back to x86 the errors/warnings all disappear.

Looking at the errors they all seem to be related to no extension methods being found, for my control events, like button clicks.

**Warnings / Errors include:**

1. Warning CS1697  Different checksum values given for 'C:...\Controls\CardFace.xaml' WildCard    C:...\obj\ARM\Debug\Controls\CardFace.g.cs 1
2. Error   CS1061  'AboutPlanningPoker' does not contain a definition for 'appBack_Click' and no extension method 'appBack_Click' accepting a first argument of type 'AboutPlanningPoker' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) WildCard    C:...\obj\ARM\Debug\AboutPlanningPoker.g.cs......\AboutPlanningPoker.xaml

Comment: just do a rebuild. This normally happen when you done some changes and change the configuration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing a 'Clean Solution' on it seemed to do the trick.